# Setting different publishing scenario between two publications

Tags: publishing

May I know was there any apporach to setup different publishing scenario between two publications, for example from **Publication A** bulk (more no. of items) publishing is carried out and in **Publication B** only very few items are being published. In this case publishing activity in **Publication A** should not affect publishing in **Publication B**. Any suggestions on how it can be achieved.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Out-of-box publishing sytem only picks item based on Priority(High,Normal,Low) so need some  customizations for your requirement.

Please check following post from Chris for this specific topic

http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/filtering-prioritization-of-the-tridion-publish-queue

Answer (score 1):

The BB article referenced by @Raj should answer your question (assuming you have multiple publishers).

If you are limited to one publisher, you might consider creating two Publication Targets (Target A and Target B). You would set the Priority for Target A to Normal (or possibly Low), and Target B to High. This way Publication B items will never get stuck in the Publication Q behind A items for very long.

It is not the perfect solution, but should solve your problem if you only have a single publisher.